# WooCommerce Subscriptions - Automatic switching of cost and interval

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I'm using WooCommerce Subscriptions/Memberships and am pretty certain what I'm trying to achieve isn't possible out of the box. Essentially I want three options of billing intervals:

$15 per week for 12 weeks.

$60 per month for 3 months.

$180 up front.

I know how to do the above using Variable Subscriptions, however the problem is that I need it to change over to $9.95 per week for all three of the above after 12 weeks is up. Does anyone have any ideas about how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar, but on different trigger. Anyway, I changed the product inside the subscription. All you need to do is to create another product, with the $9.95/week, and when the time comes, change the base product in the subscription, recalculate totals, setup the period and interval and save.

You need to hook woocommerce_subscription_status_expired which passes the subscription, and then manipulate the subscription. something like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_status_expired', 'change_subscription_base_product', 10, 1 );

function change_subscription_base_product($subscription){
       $subscription->remove_order_items();
       $args = array(); //you can change here to total etc..
       $productId = 123;/Change this to be dynamic or to hard coded product ID

       $product = wc_get_product($productId); 

       $subscription->add_product($product, 1, $args);
       $subscription->calculate_totals();
       $subscription->set_billing_period(WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_period($productId));
       $subscription->set_billing_interval(WC_Subscriptions_Product::get_interval($productId));
       $subscription->save();
}
```